# angular2: How to get a component instance from ActivatedRoute?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I would like to call currently active component's method from [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate) guard method.
I tried it this way, but the retrieved *currentComponent* is just a component function, not an instance:

```
@Injectable()
export class ReservationGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private router: Router){

  }

  canActivate( route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    const currentComponent = this.router.routerState.root.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.component;

    // I'd like to call component's instance method which returns Observable<boolean>
    // return currentComponent.submit()

    return true;

  }
}
```

[CanDeactivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate) guard offers a component instance but I need it in [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) guard.

---

I already shuffled in some service with EventEmitter to make it work, but it looked like a bad design smell with unnecessary 'asynchronicity'.

CanActivate guard return:

```
return Observable.create( newObservable => {

    this.reservationService.submitCurrentForm().subscribe(lastValidStep => 
      newObservable.next(lastValidStep + 1 >= navigatingStep)
    );

  });
```

ReservationService:

```
submitCurrentForm(): Observable<number> {
    this.submitEndEmitter = new ReplaySubject(1);
    this.submitCurrentFormEmitter.next();
    return this.submitEndEmitter;
  }
```

Component:

```
  this.reservationService.getSubmitCurrentFormEmitter().subscribe( () => 
      this.submit()
  );
```

Comment: You'll probably need to shuffle some code into a service and then import that service into both your component and guard. Can you post the component code and what are you trying to do in a broader sense?

Comment: I believe `canActivate` is called before the component instance is created

Comment: @Hayden, thx for your comment, I already did that... You can see it in the updated question now

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com yes that is true for the component we are navigating to... I need to access the currently active component we are navigating from

Comment: @DarkPatronusLinX then you probably want to use the `CanDeactivate` guard instead